# Contradiction of node versions on Mac OSX

Tags: node.js, xcode, macos, terminal, homebrew

I wanted to run Angular6 which has been released a couple of days back. So the system gave me an error that my node version was lower than 8.9. So I did the following steps. But it seems the system has two versions of node running independently.

[image: Checked node version]
Checked node version

[image: Node present in brew list]
Node present in brew list

[image] Tried To upgrade node but is says that version 10.0.0 is already installed. But then if I check the version it still displays v6.11.4

Help Required!

Comment: Can you show the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: and what is your macOS version?

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin

Comment: and the output of  `which node`?

Comment: I DO NOT understand @OrtomalaLokni

Comment: What is the result of typing `which node` into your terminal?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/node This

Answer (score 0):

The node version installed with Homebrew should be located first in you `PATH` environment variable.

Add to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
#Homebrew
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

or modify your `PATH` accordingly.

Comment: Rest of the things I have installed are working perfectly fine. The problem is only with node. So I guess that is not the problem.

Comment: The snippet above is useful only to determine the priority between two commands with the same name.